# How to generate a basic HTML (<p> and <br>) version of another cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, html

I'm using Google Sheets to help prepare posts for various social media sites.  For some of the sites, I need to cut-and-paste HTML because my posts contain YouTube videos, and the only way to avoid using the site's UI is to post HTML directly.

So, in my sheet, I have a column **main text** with content such as this:

> Paragraph 1
>
> (empty line)
>
> Paragraph 2
>
> (empty line)
>
> Paragraph 3

Now I want to make another column (**basic html**) that references **main text**:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<br>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<br>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

Here is how my data is formatted:

- There is always at least one paragraph.  There may be as many as five paragraphs.
- There is always an empty line between paragraphs.

So this is what I want to do:

- If a line contains text, add a `<p>` tag in front and a `</p>` tag in back.
- If there is an empty line, convert it into a `<br>` tag.

I have read through the list of Google Sheets functions and I have some basic familiarity with the Script Editor, but I don't know what direction to take to try to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a pretty formula, but I got this to work (replace `A1` with cell that has the source text to perform the modifications on):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE("<p>", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "

", "
<br>
"), "
", "</p>
<p>"), "</p>"), "<p><br></p>", "<br>")
```

[image: example of substitution done by formula]

Note that the line breaks in the formula are important. This also assumes that the first line of the cell is not an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't verified this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"<br>",CONCATENATE("<p>",A1,"</p>"))
```

In other words...

*if* the cell A1 is blank, *then* return a "`<br>`", *else*, return the contents of A1 concatenated with a prepended "`<p>`" and appended "`</p>`".

[image: sample output]

Then just autofill for as many cells as you need.

Comment: This would work if it were one line per cell, but I think the question is asking about performing this modification for multiple lines within one cell.

Comment: @ChristopherSu: If that's the case, then the Asker is _really_ using the wrong tools for the job.

Comment: Agreed, still a fun formula-writing exercise though :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which will work if all the text is in a single cell, and doesn't require funky line breaks in the formula.

```
=concatenate("<p>",substitute(A1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),concatenate("</p>",CHAR(10),"<br>",CHAR(10),"<p>")),"</p>")
```

[image: sample output]

This assumes, however, that the paragraphs are separated with a regular line feed character (`U+000A`), which you can generally get in Google Sheets by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.